# responsive web page content does not load in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've built a responsive landing page that functions correctly but doesn't load up right in mobile.  If I view the page on my machine, with a normal window size, no issues. If functions, scrolls and when I resize it to smaller scale, the CSS does it's thing.

**However**, when I test it with the browser at it's smallest width, or when I test it thru my iPhone, the page comes up blank. No images, no copy. Nothing. I've been able to figure out that anything below 768px wide is where I run into issues.

I've run dev tools to try and narrow it down but one of the first things I've noticed is that none of my HTML code shows up.

My original inclination was that the background images are too heavy so I optimized them with tinyjpg, which got them down in file size but it didn't affect the mobile load. I also tried going to the CSS and commenting out each line for those specific images, but that affected nothing (though when I looked thru dev tools, all of the code was populating). From that point, I figured that it's not related to my images. I've tried commenting out chunks of CSS starting at the bottom (instruction for max-width 420) but again, no real affect.

https://jsfiddle.net/snottrocket/4tqytLws/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Demo - Simple responsive parallax website tutorial</title>
        <meta name="description" content="descriptive content here">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />



       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://review.bkv.com/BKV/2015/EmailTimelineLander/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://review.bkv.com/BKV/2015/EmailTimelineLander/css/main_SO.css"> 
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="loading">
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        
    <ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#slide-2"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#slide-3"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#slide-4"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#slide-5"><span></span></a></li>

 </ul>
 
 <ul id="nav-list">
  <li>1971</li>
  <li>1978</li>
  <li>1991</li>
  <li>1992</li>
 </ul>   
 
        
        <main>
         <section id="slide-1" class="homeSlide">
          <div class="bcg">
     <div class="hsEgg" id="eggBg1">
      <div class="hsContainer">
          <div class="hsContent">
        <h2>The History of Email</h2>
         <div id="redbar">&nbsp;</div>
        <article id="history">You probably get dozens upon dozens delivered to your inbox everyday. Some expected, some unexpected, and some downright spooky. But do we ever stop and think about where email marketing all began? Let’s go back. Way back. </article>
         </div>
           </div>
    </div> 
          </div>
      </section>
     <section id="slide-2" class="homeSlide">
          <div class="bcg">
     <div class="hsEgg" id="eggBg2"> 
      <div class="hsContainer">
       <div class="hsContent">
        <h1>1971</h1>
        <div id="redbar">&nbsp;</div>
        <h2>You've Got Mail</h2>
        <article id="history">Ray Tomlinson sends the first-ever email while working on ARPANET, the government’s precursor to the Internet.</article>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
      </div> 
      </section>
      
      <section id="slide-3" class="homeSlide">
       <div class="bcg">
     <div class="hsEgg" id="eggBg3">
         <div class="hsContainer">
          <div class="hsContent">
           <h1>1978</h1>
        <div id="redbar">&nbsp;</div>
        <h2>The Spam Father</h2>
        <article id="history">Gary Thuerk, marketing manager at Digital Equipment Corporation, sends the first mass-marketing email to 400 users and it generated $13 million in sales.</article>
          </div>
            </div>
     </div> 
       </div>
      </section>
      <section id="slide-4" class="homeSlide">
       <div class="bcg">
     <div class="hsEgg" id="eggBg4">
      <div class="hsContainer">
       <div class="hsContent">
           <h1>1991</h1>
        <div id="redbar">&nbsp;</div>
        <h2>Happy birthday, internet</h2>
        <article id="historyC">The Internet hits the scene and changes the world forever.</article>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div> 
       </div>
      </section>   
      
   <section id="slide-5" class="homeSlide">
    <div class="bcg">
     <div class="hsEgg" id="eggBg5">     
        <div class="hsContainer">
         <div class="hsContent">
           <h1>1992</h1>
        <div id="redbar">&nbsp;</div>
        <h2>Get it on the go!</h2>
        <article id="historyC">Mobile email access is now possible thanks to the first smart phone.</article>
         </div>
        </div>
     </div>
       </div>
   </section>
   
  

  </main>

         
 
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://review.bkv.com/BKV/2015/EmailTimelineLander/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="https://review.bkv.com/BKV/2015/EmailTimelineLander/js/imagesloaded.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="js/enquire.min.js"></script>-->  
        <script src="https://review.bkv.com/BKV/2015/EmailTimelineLander/js/skrollr.js"></script>
        <script src="https://review.bkv.com/BKV/2015/EmailTimelineLander/js/_main.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
  <script src="https://review.bkv.com/BKV/2015/EmailTimelineLander/js/jquery.nav.js"></script>

  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav').onePageNav();
   });
  </script> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

*edit - added link to [actual page](https://review.bkv.com/BKV/2015/EmailTimelineLander/index.html)

Comment: Are you getting a 404?  Are you actually hosting the page over your network?  Are you able to debug this using developer tools such as OSX Safari with debugging enabled?  What about whenever you use [device mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/) in Chrome?

Comment: The code does not show up below 768px? So the code is generated? My guess is that there might be the problem.

Comment: @zero298 

 - No 404 errors. I've been testing locally but I did put it up on our review server as well, same problem.
- I've been using dev tools in Chrome.  Noticed the same issue with device mode.

Comment: @Thomas Correct, below 768, the code doesn't show up..at least in the developer tools view. I can right-click and view code and see my code, otherwise.

Comment: If you aren't able to fit your code including CSS here, you may want to put it into a jsfiddle.  It would be better to edit your HTML down to the minimum code necessary to reproduce the issue, but a fiddle wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Ah yes. Link has been added at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Questions about debugging on Stack Overflow require a [mcve]. The code that you have posted is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to ensure that the code **in your question** is **Minimal** (only the code necessary to reproduce), **Complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **Verifiable** (we should be able to reproduce the issue using only the code in your question, nothing less and nothing more). As it is your question is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks @Kyll. 
 I revised the post accordingly. Hopefully up to snuff.